# Installing SAGA-GIS wants to remove packages

Tags: software-center, software-installation

Trying to install SAGA-GIS (saga 2.1.0+dfsg-1build2) using the Software Center in Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit). The problem is that the software center tries to remove:

-libgdal1
  -libopenscenegraph80
  -libosgearth1
  -libqgis2.2.0
  -qgis
  -qgis-plugin-globe
  -qgis-plugin-grass
  -qgis-providers

How can I avoid uninstalling those other programs?

Comment: Use apt-get to install the package, edit your question and add the output.

Answer (score 0):

Ok not sure how I fixed it because I tried around with different repositories and Ubuntu updated itself twice.

Maybe adding this repository was the solution:

```
  deb     http://qgis.org/debian-nightly trusty main
```